# installed shared library version number does not match LT_VERSION_INFO

Tags: shared-libraries, gnu, autotools, libtool

The libtool versioning number of a shared library is set in `configure.ac` via

`LT_VERSION_INFO="lt_current:lt_revision:lt_age"`

but when I set it to `0:1:0` `make install` installs the `lib..so.0.0.1`, and when I set it to `3:2:1` it installs `lib..so.2.1.2`. This does not seem right. If it is, can someone please explain what's going on? Otherwise, what could be wrong? The libtool version is 2.4.2.

I am familiar with the fact libtool versions differ from release version. That is not the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [this explanation and example](https://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_61.html#Library-Versioning) useful; there are others similar to it on the net, but this one has a practical workflow at the end (as does the documentation for libtool).  So, with this in mind, let's run through your examples for `-version-info`:

> 0:1:0

Says to `libtool`: for API 0, I have made one change to the source files, and no backward-compatible additions to the API.

Now `libtool` abstracts the shared library building process away from the real platform tools so that you can just drop an autotools built tarball on a system and type `./configure && make && make install` and have a reasonable chance of working software at the end of that build.  Some platforms will care about the contents of `-version-info` (e.g. Linux, which I'm kind of assuming that you are building for, so you'll see `libfoo.so.0.0.1`), and others will not (e.g. Android, so you'll see `libfoo.so`), and there's others that somewhat care.  Since `libtool` has to span different platforms, they had to come up with a scheme that would allow them to compute the right values on *all* their target platforms.  And that's why the numbering is somewhat unintuitive.

So on Linux, "0:1:0" translates to `libfoo.so.0.0.1` since the linker uses a *major*`.`*minor*`.`*patchlevel* scheme for differentiating libraries.  On another OS, this may be different, or nonexistent.

> 3:2:1

Says to `libtool`: for API 2, I have made one backward-compatible change to the API, and two subsequent source changes.  You get the API number by (*current* - *age*) = (3 - 1) = 2.  You know that you have subsequent changes since *revision* gets reset to 0 on any API change (and *current* gets incremented).  And so on Linux that means you get `libfoo.so.2.1.2`.